# Arel::SelectManager how to access the result including the projections

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arel

I am attempting to access the results of a join where columns of both tables are specified as part of a projection.

I have 2 models (Rails 4.2.11; Arel 6.0.4; Ruby 2.5.3)

```rb
# Table name: users
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  name       :string(255)
#  email      :string(255)
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos
end

# Table name: photos
#
#  id            :integer          not null, primary key
#  name          :string(255)
#  created_by_id :integer
#  assigned_id   :integer
#  created_at    :datetime         not null
#  updated_at    :datetime         not null
#  user_id       :integer

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

```rb
creators = User.arel_table.alias('creators')
updaters = User.arel_table.alias('updaters')
photos = Photo.arel_table

photos_with_credits = photos.
join(photos.join(creators, Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin).on(photos[:created_by_id].eq(creators[:id]))).
join(photos.join(updaters, Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin).on(photos[:assigned_id].eq(updaters[:id]))).
project(photos[:name], photos[:created_at], creators[:name].as('creator'), updaters[:name].as('editor'))
```

```sql
# generated SQL
SELECT photos.name, photos.created_at, creators.name AS creator, updaters.name AS editor 
FROM photos 
INNER JOIN (SELECT FROM photos LEFT OUTER JOIN users creators ON photos.created_by_id = creators.id) 
INNER JOIN (SELECT FROM photos LEFT OUTER JOIN users updaters ON photos.updated_by_id = updaters.id)
```

How I'd like to process the result

```rb
photos_with_credits.map{|x| "#{photo.name} - copyright #{photo.created_at.year} #{photo.creator}, edited by #{photo.editor}"}.join('; ')
```

This may be a very dumb question, but ...
I have not been able to find a way to use the SelectManager result to produce a meaningful output since map was deprecated (& removed) from the SelectManager class.

I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Simplified the activerecord / arel query builder

#### amended code

```rb
photos_with_credits = Photo.select([photos[:name], photos[:created_at], creators[:name].as('creator'), updaters[:name].as('editor')]).
joins(photos.outer_join(creators).on(photos[:created_by_id].eq(creators[:id])).join_sources).
joins(photos.outer_join(updaters).on(photos[:assigned_id].eq(updaters[:id])).join_sources)

photos_with_credits.map do |photo|
  puts "#{photo.name} - copyright #{photo.created_at.year} #{photo.creator}, edited by #{photo.editor}".light_blue
end
```

amended SQL (simpler)

```sql
SELECT photos.name, photos.created_at, creators.name AS creator, updaters.name AS editor 
FROM photos 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN users creators ON photos.created_by_id = creators.id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN users updaters ON photos.assigned_id = updaters.id
```

Answer (score 0):

We should figure out a way to trigger SelectManage and get `ActiveRelation` result, then we can iterate it by using `map`, etc.

So I would like to suggest:

```
Photo.join(photos_with_credits.join_sources).map do |photo|
  "#{photo.name} - copyright #{photo.created_at.year} #{photo.creator}, edited by #{photo.editor}"}.join('; ')
end
```

Comment: Thank you. It does indeed generate an ActiveRelation. However, it also results in an error "undefined method `table_name' for #<Arel::SelectManager:0x000055dc3cdb0e48>". I can't see where that might be coming from (apart from the SelectManager). What am I missing?

Comment: On further research, I've changed the query ```photos_with_credits``` as above which now works. Still haven't been able to find any documentation on ```join_sources```.

Comment: It's really hard to find out the documentation for SelectManager, since Arel lib has been merge to Rails repository. You can check its method by referring this one https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4f12139a22f70ff0abc1709b8888011f8bfee42c/activerecord/lib/arel/select_manager.rb#L232. Anyway, if you think `join_sources` resolved your problem, please give me 1 upvote.